# Debugging user mode process exception from kernel debugger (windbg)

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg

I'm trying to debug a user mode ELAM (Early Launch Anti-Malware) service (which has Protected Process Light(PPL) protection) exception from kernel debugger (WinDbg).

I've tried to use GFlags (`+sue +soe +d32 +eel +ksl`) but I get huge amount of unrelated exceptions.
I've also tried to use `.process` but I don't get any exceptions from the user mode process.

How can I debug user mode process from kernel debugger, and receive it exceptions ?

Comment: can you fill the details about why you have to use a kd for debugging an user mode process? why not use a user mode windbg to debug it ? have you tried ntsd -d method?  asfar as gflags do you mean  +ksl ? keep inmind sxe ld: will only work once per boot if you are doing  that

Comment: @blabb I'm debugging ELAM service which is PPL therefore it can't be debugged from user mode.